# jQuery Offset().left doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I have a question about jQuery offset() function. I use it on my site to display "email a friend" window after clicking on email icon.

However, the window appears sticked to the right side of browser's window, not on the position of the icon. You can see it in action on http://pec.solarismedia.net/calendarday.html

```
$(".emailFriend").hide();
    $(".emailIcon").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".emailFriend").css({
            "position": "absolute", 
            "left": $(this).offset().left, 
            "top": $(this).offset().top
        }).fadeIn(500);
        return false; 
    });
```

There is a picture showing the difference between intention and reality. 
[image]

Comment: Regardless of the JS solution you accept, it'd make sense to position the `.emailtofriend` modal via CSS. Contain the element inside `.userTools` and position with relative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because `#container` has `position: relative;`. Thus absolute settings of the email box are relative to the #container. You have to either remove the property or calculate the value of `left` with something like this:

```
$(this).offset().left - $('#container').offset().left
```

Comment: what if there is no '#container' around?

Comment: @iRaS: that's a rather meaningless change of circumstances. What if there's no `.emailIcon`?

Comment: I'd ask even more important question: What if there's no JS enabled in user's browser? ;)

Comment: @DavidHedlund thats no problem because then `$('.emailIcon').on("click", function() {});` has no effect at all.

Answer (score 3):

just use position istead. 
The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document.

```js
$(".emailFriend").insertBefore('.emailIcon').hide();
$(".emailIcon").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".emailFriend").css({
        "position": "absolute", 
        "left": $(this).position().left, 
        "top": $(this).position().top
    }).fadeIn(500);
    return false; 
});
```

added appendTo('.userTools'). an element showing at the same position than another should be within the same element. Then position works and will work even if you change the layout.

If you don't want to change the dom structure for any reason you should use something like this:

```
$(".emailFriend").hide();
$(".emailIcon").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".emailFriend").css({
        "position": "absolute", 
        "left": $(this).offset().left-$(".emailFriend").offsetParent().offset().left, 
        "top": $(this).offset().top-$(".emailFriend").offsetParent().offset().top
    }).fadeIn(500);
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: This code won't work either, have you tested? `$(this).position().top` is equal 0 because the `position()` method **does not** calculate the values the way CSS will. CSS will position elements relating to the closest ancestor with `position: relative;` while jQuery takes only the parent into consideration.

Comment: @Miszy wow - i'm sorry. the position method is exactly for such issues. the only problem was the dom structure where .emailFriend is not within the same element as .emailIcon.

Comment: i just played a little bit with the second answer and added an if-statement: `if ($('.emailFriend').offset().left+$('.emailFriend').width() > $(window).width()) {
  $('.emailFriend').css('left', $(window).width()-$('.emailFriend').outerWidth()-$('.emailFriend').offsetParent().offset().left-20);
}` just to make shure its not overlapping the view port